# How to pass "yes" when pipeline asks an answer?

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm trying to deploy a laravel app to my server. Here is my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:7.3

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# Variables
variables:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_USER: username
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: database
  DB_HOST: localhost:3306
  PUBLIC_URL: https://example.com

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - my-tag
    - another-tag
  script:
    - echo "Building deploy package"
    - echo "composer install"
    - composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
    - mysql --version
    - echo "Migrating database"
    - php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
    - echo "Dumping mysql database"
    - mysqldump --host="${DB_HOST}" --user="${MYSQL_USER}" --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" "${MYSQL_DATABASE}" > db.sql
    - php artisan config:cache
    - php artisan route:cache
    - php artisan view:cache

    - echo "Build successful"
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - build

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - my-tag
    - another-tag
  script:
    - echo "Current Directory:"
    - pwd
    - ls
    - echo "Deploying to server"
    - sudo cp -rv build/* /var/www/vhosts/example.com/
    - echo "Deployed"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://example.com
  only:
    - master
```

But it gives this error:

```
...
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
$ echo "Migrating database"
Migrating database
$ php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************
 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > Command Canceled!
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I'm using docker on `gitlab-runner`.

How can I handle this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan` has a `--no-interaction` flag you can use so it doesn't wait for a "yes" from an interactive user. E.g.:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --no-interaction
```

Comment: `
$ php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --no-interaction
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************
Command Canceled!
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
`
It still gives this error.

Comment: I think, this problem is another issue. But your answer is correct. Thank you.